# Deploying Fastlane and Jenkins to Server for iOS

Tags: ios, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd, fastlane

Recently I started working on implementing CI/CD on my iOS app. I have implemented it locally using Jenkins and Fastlane. When the Jenkins job is build everything works and apps are uploaded based on that. The issue right now is everything is done locally and I'm the only one in my team. But if my team were to grow in the future I would have to do this remotely using a server. I've googled alot and found out that Fastlane for iOS doesn't support Linux as we need Xcode command lines to build the app which is not supported by Linux. So, I was wondering how I can go on about deploying it to a remote server.

Any help is appreciated and please comment if you need more information on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use Jenkins for iOS development, you can set up your Jenkins server on Linux, macOS, or Windows; it mostly doesn't matter (though the command line may vary slightly, depending on your preferences).

Afterward, you can configure an agent node for your iOS jobs. This node needs to be macOS-based, with everything installed, such as Xcode, xcodebuild, etc. You can locate it at the `https://yourjenkinsurl/computer/` URL.

You can learn more about nodes from documentation:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

Side note: I understand this question is about Jenkins, but if you're considering setting up a new server for CI/CD, I would recommend trying GitLab. It's easier to set up GitLab runners for jobs compared to configuring agent nodes in Jenkins. :)